# Isabelle Archive of formal proof dependency graph

Tags: isabelle

I was wondering whether these is some tool that could help me find packages in AFP that depend on some specific package.

For example I see that `Jacobson_Basic_Algebra`
https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Jacobson_Basic_Algebra.html
has been used as a basis for definitions in `Grothendieck_Schemes` https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Grothendieck_Schemes.html# . I was wondering whether there exists some extension of `Jacobson_Basic_Algebra` to the theory of fields.